# How To Consume JMS Queue From WSO2 REST API

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 EI 6.1.1. I am trying to consume Active MQ queue from inside the WSO2 REST API, but unable to achieve it. I don't want to use the proxy service of WSO2. Please provide some input.

Comment: Please include what you have tried

Comment: Hi Riyafa I am trying to create rest web service which will consume message from jms queue (Active MQ) and send queue message as a response to the client.

Comment: Yes include an example api you have created and state what's not working

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 provides the JMS [connector](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/e57e41ab-7795-47f1-af4d-071fed5755da). Can you try with this?